# How to destroy a dynamically created DOM element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am creating a dynamic span inside a span with some form elements and creating button with data-id inside the same dynamically  by jquery append in span #add_more. I want to remove that particular span when button of that span is clicked.

Step1.

```
<input type="button" value="Add More" id="more_size">
<span id="add_more"></span>
```

2.Clicked on Add More button :-

```
<input type="button" value="Add More" id="more_size">
<span id="add_more">
    <span id="1001"><input type="text" name="price[]">
    <button data-id="1001" type="button">X</button></span>
</span>
```

3.When clicked on button with id 1001 span with id 1001 should removed using jquery remove().

```
<input type="button" value="Add More" id="more_size">
<span id="add_more"></span>
```

I am new to stack overflow. This is the best way I can explain my problem.

Comment: Do you have a click handler on the 'X' button? If so, it would be `$(this).parent().empty()` from inside that handler.

Answer (score 1):

use like this:

```
function removeSpan(spanId) {
   $("#"+spanId).remove();
}
```

call `removeSpan` using `spanid`.

to pass id you can do like this:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
     id = $(this).data('id');// since your data-id and span id are same
     removeSpan(id);
});
```

or at the time of creation it self you can add the function and pass the id which you have assigned.

Comment: So how do you get `spanId`? I guess this is the point of the question

Comment: hi wolf refer the below answer

Comment: If you're creating the span then presumably you can control what its `id` is. But you haven't told us how you're creating it. Alternatively, if you're creating a jquery object, you could just use that object in place of `$("#"+spanId)`.

Answer (score 1):

have a common class on button get data-id of the button clicked...

```
<span id="add_more">
  <span id="1001"><input type="text" name="price[]">
  <button data-id="1001" type="button" class='remove_class'>X</button></span>
</span>
```

add click event listener to that button using it class (remove_class).

```
$(document).on('click','.remove_class',function(){
     id = $(this).data('id');
     $('#'+id).remove();
});
```

you can add any number span. using class get current clicked button very easy.

Comment: Ya sounds good but unclear if OP wants to remove `<input type="text" name="price[]">` too or not. His provided HTML markup suggests ya but there is no reference regarding it in question.

Comment: or else if want remove esp that textbox assign it's id like this  <input type="text" name="price[]" id="txt_1001"> ... then remove that like this  $('#txt_'+id).remove();

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev) method:

```
$("#add_more").on("click", "button", function() {
  $(this).prev().remove();
});
```

If you want to remove the button as well, you can use [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/):

```
$("#add_more").on("click", "button", function() {
 $(this).prev().addBack().remove();
});
```

I don't suggest manually generating `id`'s,`data-*` attributes etc for this purpose (*If above mentioned is the sole purpose of generating them*), often times you can avoid doing so using a common class and proper methods.